# onclick event is not working on Link

Tags: php, jquery

I have serverside processing enabled in my datatable. I'm using the following code for my datatable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table = $('#FullDataDisplay').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "server_processing.php",
    "aoColumnDefs": [            
 {
   "aTargets": [ 2 ], // Column to target
   "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
     return '<a id=' + full[0] + ' class="edit-link" href="#" title="Edit">' + data + '</a>';
   }
 }
 ]
 } );
} );
</script>
```

This is correctly returning the link needed to pass to my **crud.js** script with the following:

```
/* Get Edit ID  */
    $(".edit-link").click(function()
    {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var edit_id = id;
            {
                    $(".content-loader").fadeOut('slow', function()
                     {
                            $(".content-loader").fadeIn('slow');
                            $(".content-loader").load('edit_form.php?edit_id='+edit_id);
                            $("#btn-add").hide();
                            $("#btn-view").show();
                    });
            }
            return false;
    });
    /* Get Edit ID  */
```

The problem is, when the link is clicked nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are loading the content dynamically through AJAX you need to use `$(document)`

```
/* Get Edit ID  */
$(document).on('click',".edit-link",function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var edit_id = id; {
        $(".content-loader").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(".content-loader").fadeIn('slow');
            $(".content-loader").load('edit_form.php?edit_id=' + edit_id);
            $("#btn-add").hide();
            $("#btn-view").show();
        });
    }
    return false;
});
/* Get Edit ID  */
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that - Thank you!

Comment: Happens sometimes anyways glad it helped.. :)